# Working with forms in Django and checking if all the input fields are entered

Tags: python, django

I have created a contact page and there I created a form that looks like this

[image]

Now I want that 'submit' button to check whether all the input fields are entered. If it is then I want to activate the

`<form action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="post">`

Otherwise no post method activation. Instead a popup message box will appear telling that "Please enter all the fields"
[image]

If post method is activated, I want to go to the {% url 'contact' %} that is my views.py file and check if the system is able to retrieve all the values from the input fields.

[image]

If it does it will render a fresh contact page return render(request, 'myapp/contact.html')
And popup another message box to the browser that "Form is submitted successfully"
Else another message box to the browser that "There is an error occurred submitting the form"

I really can't find a way to implement this. I am a newbie is Django and Python. I have very minimum experience in html and CSS. But no JavaScript, though I used a small JavaScript code, I wish to completely use Python, HTML and CSS. Is that possible to implement this scenario using my desired language?

If yes, please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Django forms. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form

Create a contact form with the form class, pass it into the template. It will make the HTML tags for default browser validation. It will also allow backend validation when the form is submitted. You can then redirect the user if the form is valid or invalid.

If you wanted to do it from scratch you could do the following.

In your HTML make sure you add required attribute to the required input fields

```
<input name="name" type="text" ... required ... >
```

Import messages from django messages, check user input is valid, add message and render contact.html . This will send a message into the template. You can style the message with HTML and CSS.

In views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages

if request.method == POST:
    ...
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    if name == '':
        messages.warning(request, 'Please enter name !')
        return render(request, 'myapp/contact.html')
    ...
```

Comment: Is not it possible to do it from scratch?

Comment: You can do it from scratch, I have edited the answer to include that option. In my opinion the form class is better, it adds more features.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on client side validation. To validate, none of the fields should be left blank. Like this

```
function validateForm() {
    var isValid = true;
         $('.form-field').each(function() {
              if ( $(this).val() === '' )
                   confirm("All Fields are required!");
                    isValid = false;
           });
     return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look at my code if simple just make an if statement like I did look the second and third line

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['password1']   == '':
            return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error': 'Please fill all the fileds '})
        elif request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
(YOUR CODE HERE )
```